# Mutable default arguments in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I have written the following python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def bug( numbers = [] ):
    numbers.append( 1 )
    return numbers

print bug()
print bug()
```

The result i would expect is

```
[1]
[1]
```

But i got

```
[1]
[1, 1]
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a bug and this behaviour has been around in Python for a very long time.

The problem is that the list object is mutable, i.e. you can change it, and when you call a function you don't get a new default value. What's happening is this:

```
def bug( numbers = [] ):
   numbers.append( 1 )
   return numbers
```

At this point the function `bug` has been created and the list that is default value for `numbers` created.

```
print bug()
```

Now we've called bug once and added `1` to the list that was created when the function was defined.

```
print bug()
```

When we call the function again we get the same list as before so we get two `1`s added to the list.

The usual solution is to define your function as follows:

```
def bug(numbers = None):
    if numbers is None:
        numbers = []
    numbers.append(1)
    return numbers
```

Read [this](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`numbers=[]` is evaluated only once (when the function is defined). So it's always the same list.

To avoid this, change the function like this:

```
def not_a_bug(numbers=None):
    if numbers is None:
        numbers = []
    numbers.append(1)
    return numbers
```